# How do I print a statement in a recursive Python function only once in the first iteration?

Tags: python, function, recursion

I need to write a function that prints a timer as output (everything at the same time). However, I need to write "Ready?" at the beginning, so I only want it to be printed once.

Here's what I have so far:

```
def factorial(i):
    while i > 0:
        print(i)
        return (factorial(i-1))
    print('Go!')

factorial(5)
```

I want the function to print the output like so:

```
Ready?    
5
4
3
2
1
Go!
```

Comment: Also, the `while` should be an `if`, logically. It works because you always `return` out of it, but it doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @HampusLarsson it's a recursive function, that won't make any difference...

Comment: Refactor your code please

Comment: also your indentation is wrong and in Python it matters, so you should fix it

Comment: Is your function recursive or iterative?

Comment: @GPhilo Recursion has little to do with it. More importantly, the `return` statement is unconditional, so the loop *can't* iterate more than once.

Comment: Why is this function called `factorial`, anyway? It's just counting down from an initial argument.

Comment: @chepner My comment refers to Hampus' now-deleted comment about putting the print before the while. Since this is a recursive function, the print would run N times, not just one, and the specific placemnt of it won't make a difference on how many times it gets printed (excluding the case "not printed at all because the code is not reached", ofc)

Comment: Anyway, why not just do the printing outside the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an [inner function](https://realpython.com/inner-functions-what-are-they-good-for/):

```
def factorial(i):
    def recursive_output(i):
        if i > 0:
            print(i)
            recursive_output(i-1)

    print("Ready!")
    recursive_output(i)
    print("Go!")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add an argument to the function

```
FIRST_TIME = True
NOT_FIRST_TIME = False


def factorial(i, is_first_time):
    if is_first_time:
        print('Ready?')
    if i:
        print(i)
        return (factorial(i-1, NOT_FIRST_TIME))
    print('Go!')


factorial(5, FIRST_TIME)
```

Comment: You can use just one flag and set it to false after printing.